# Ruby on Rails Glyphicons Button Rooting Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glyphicons

For Example i have a new_Path for the Page/new. How can i link the Path  in my Button_Code?! Has anyone an idea ?

I will click on this button and than i will go to "new"page in my Programm.

thanks for help

```
<i> <div class="center jumbotron">
<div>
 <center-right>
  <button  type="button" class="btn btn-info">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Mitnehmgelegenheit inserien!

  </button>
</center-right>

  <center-left>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Mitnehmgelegenheit suchen!
  </button>
</centerleft>

<i>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the button_to helper

```
<%= button_to new_path, {class: "btn btn-info"} do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Mitnehmgelegenheit inserien!
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I have understood you want to have a button that will redirect to new page on clicking.You can do this using link_to tag and add bootstrap button classes to it in the following manner.

```
<%= link_to '+ New ', new_path, class: 'btn btn-info' %>
```